# Positioning of Slicknav menu

Tags: jquery, css, slicknav

I want to center align my Slicknav menu button but can't for the life of me figure out how. I've spent days editing the CSS to no avail. I also don't want it to be fixed to the top of the page (I want to put a div with social media buttons above it), but whenever I edit the prependTo property to anything except 'body' the whole menu disappears.

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">Home</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">News</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">Books</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">Bio</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">Extras</a></li>
        <li class="main"><a href="#" class="nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>


#nav-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav({
        label:'MENU',
        prependTo:'nav-wrapper',
        closeOnClick:'true' // Close menu when a link is clicked.
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post some code here

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem. I wasn't putting the pound sign before the div ID in the prependTo line. This works:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#menu').slicknav({
        label:'MENU',
        prependTo:'#nav-wrapper',
        closeOnClick:'true' // Close menu when a link is clicked.
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post some code so we can see what you're doing!

So far though the usual problem is that you'll need to wrap your sticky nav:

```
<body>
    <div class="sticky-nav-wrapper">
        <div class="sticky-nav"> STICKY NAV </div>
    </div>

...content
</body>

.sticky-nav-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.sticky-nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Something like that any way.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've managed to center align the menu, but I still can't add any elements above it. I've added the relevant code to my original post above. I see the menu when it says prependTo:'body',  but when I change it to 'nav-wrapper' the whole menu disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Jquery.slicknav.js**, one option is here **prependTo: 'body'**, So if you want to place the mobile nav under you custom section please change the class name in this option For Example **prependTo: '.custom-nav'**, Enjoy :)